# Different values of mean absolute error when using GridSearchCV for max_leaf_nodes vs manually optimising max_leaf_nodes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees, python-3.x, gridsearchcv

[image: manually optimizing parameter]

[image: using GridSearchCV to optimize parameter]

I am trying out hyperparameter tuning vs manually selecting the best parameter (`max_leaf_nodes`) on a decision tree model with mean absolute error as the scoring. In theory, both should give me the same MAE and `max_leaf_nodes`; but, both are giving me different MAEs. Also, if I change the value of cv in GridSearchCV I get different results. So basically I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting different `max_leaf_nodes` and MAE in both cases?
2. How do I determine the value of cv in GridsearchCV, because I get different results for cv = 3, cv = 5, and cv = 10?

Comment: I am not sure how big the difference is, but since you are not specifying a seed in the second example the results will differ depending on the seed.

Comment: I tried setting the seed to 69 everywhere. But still I'm getting different values for mean absolute error and max_leaf_nodes. When performing GridSearchCV mae= 27378 and best max_leaf_nodes = 100 but whne manually optimizing mae = 28202 and max_leaf_nodes = 50!

Comment: That might be explained by the default scorer that is used when using `GridSearchCV`, see also [this stackexchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348975/9435355).

Comment: Please do not insert images of code; paste the code into a code-formatted block instead.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I've used the same scoring (mean absolute error) in both the cases. Also the seeds are same everywhere. Still not getting similar results!

Comment: @BenReiniger My bad. Noted for future questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manual approach gives the MAE on the test set.  Because you've set an integer for the parameter `cv`, the `GridSearchCV` is doing [k-fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) cross-validation (see the parameter description in [grid search docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)), and so the score `.best_score_` is the average MAE on the multiple test folds.

If you really want a single train/test split, you can do that in `GridSearchCV`, see e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31948879/10495893).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in the first case, I am getting mae based on only the "test set" but when using gridsearch I am getting mae based on the multiple sets of "train set" since I set cv = 5? Am I correct?